# How to display a dynamic sub field in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a dynamic forms application in angular.js and I'm stuck on how to access sub objects in a list.

I have a collection of objects, and a collection of list columns.  I want to display the fields from each record in the collection depending on which columns are specified.

The code listed below works for some of the objects, but not others.  In the example, Root is displayed, but Sub.Start isn't.  I understand why it doesn't, but I'm wondering how I can get it to work.

```
var collection = 
[
    {Root: 'B', Sub: {Start: 'T' }}
];

var columns = 
[
  { Field: 'Root' },
  { Field: "Sub.Start"},
];

<tr ng-repeat="item in collection">
    <td ng-repeat="column in columns" >{{ item[column.Field] }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @charliefl - sub[Start] doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because item["Sub.Start"] doesn't exist.

Your collection would have to be structured like this:

{
    Root: "B",
    "Sub.Start": "T"
}

Comment: The collection comes from a json object, so complex types don't end up as Sub.Start.

Comment: I know, but I'm letting you know that's not how objects work, regardless of angular. Try doing console.log(collection["Sub.Start"])

Comment: Or `{ Field: 'Sub.Start'}` should be `{ Field: 'Sub'}`, which would then spit out `B {"Start":"T"}`, either way.